# How can I preserve my timerID in my react function across function calls?

Tags: reactjs

StopWatch is a child of Game, which passes a boolean value representing if it is X's turn. So my stopwatch is re-rendering after every tick and after every move. I want to start and stop my stopwatch based on this value. My problem is that clearInterval() isn't stopping the ticking.

```
  const tick = () => {
    setElapsedTime(((Date.now() - startingTime) / 1000).toFixed(2));
  }
  const timerID = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (props.xIsNext) {
    timerID.current = setInterval(
      () => tick(),
      50
    );
    }
    else {clearInterval(timerID.current, []); setElapsedTime(0);}
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerID.current, []);
    };
  }, [props.xIsNext])

  return (
    <article className="clock">
      <div>
        <h1>Stopwatch for player X</h1>
        <h2>Time: {elapsedTime}</h2>
        <h2>It is X's turn: {JSON.stringify(props.xIsNext)}</h2>
      </div>
    </article>
  );

}
```

Comment: `React.useEffect(() => { /*..*/ }, [])` try adding empty array in useEffect

Comment: Instead of this, I've added [props.xIsNext], making the useEffect run after every other turn in the tic-tac-toe game.